# Unit testing a background thread with an interface

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, interface, backgroundworker

I have created a class, `SenderClass`, which will start and run a background worker from its constructor.
The method, `RunWorker()`, runs is a `while(true)` loop which will pop elements from a queue, send them through the method `SendMessage()`, and sleep for a small amount of  time to allow new elements to be added to the queue.

Here lies the problem: How do I test the method that sends the element from the queue, without exposing it to those who uses the class?

Implementation:

```
public class SenderClass : ISenderClass
{
    private Queue<int> _myQueue = new Queue<int>();
    private Thread _worker;

    public SenderClass()
    {
        //Create a background worker
        _worker = new Thread(RunWorker) {IsBackground = true};
        _worker.Start();
    }

    private void RunWorker() //This is the background worker's method
    {
        while (true) //Keep it running
        {
            lock (_myQueue) //No fiddling from other threads
            {
                while (_myQueue.Count != 0) //Pop elements if found
                    SendMessage(_myQueue.Dequeue()); //Send the element
            }
            Thread.Sleep(50); //Allow new elements to be inserted
        }
    }

    private void SendMessage(int element)
    {
        //This is what we want to test
    }

    public void AddToQueue(int element)
    {
        Task.Run(() => //Async method will return at ones, not slowing the caller
        {
            lock (_myQueue) //Lock queue to insert into it
            {
                _myQueue.Enqueue(element);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Wanted interface:

```
public interface ISenderClass
{
    void AddToQueue(int element);
}
```

Needed interface for test purpose:

```
public interface ISenderClass
{
    void SendMessage(int element);
    void AddToQueue(int element);
}
```

There's a very simple solution, saying I have created my class incorrect due to the [Single Responsability Principle](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Single_responsibility_principle), and my class' purpose is not to send messages, but actually run what sends them.

What I should have, is another class, `TransmittingClass`, which exposes the method `SendMessage(int)` through its own interface.
This way I can test that class, and `SenderClass` should just call the method through that interface.

But what other options do I have with the current implementation?

I can make all private methods I wish to test (all of them) have a `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")]`, but does a third option exist?

Comment: Assuming that for testing purposes you expose the `SendMessage`, how would you test it? Would you not simply check if a message was sent by receiving it somewhere else?

Comment: Send message logic should be implemented in a separate class with a separate interface. This class should take the new class as a dependency.  You can test the other class separately.

Comment: I added that as a solution @axlj - Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send message logic should be implemented in a separate class with a separate interface. This class should take the new class as a dependency. You can test the new class separately.

```
public interface IMessageQueue
{
    void AddToQueue(int element);
}

public interface IMessageSender
{
    void SendMessage(object message);
}

public class SenderClass : IMessageQueue
{
    private readonly IMessageSender _sender;
    public SenderClass(IMessageSender sender)
    {
        _sender = sender;
    }
    public void AddToQueue(int element)
    {
        /*...*/
    }

    private void SendMessage()
    {
        _sender.SendMessage(new object());
    }
}

public class DummyMessageSender : IMessageSender
{
    //you can use this in your test harness to check for the messages sent
    public Queue<object> Messages { get; private set; }

    public DummyMessageSender()
    {
        Messages = new Queue<object>();
    }
    public void SendMessage(object message)
    {
        Messages.Enqueue(message);
        //obviously you'll need to do some locking here too
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To address your comment, here is an implementation using `Action<int>`.  This allows you to define your message sending action in your test class to mock the `SendMessage` method without worrying about creating another class.  (Personally, I'd still prefer to define the classes/interfaces explicitly).

```
public class SenderClass : ISenderClass
    {
        private Queue<int> _myQueue = new Queue<int>();
        private Thread _worker;
        private readonly Action<int> _senderAction;

        public SenderClass()
        {
            _worker = new Thread(RunWorker) { IsBackground = true };
            _worker.Start();
            _senderAction = DefaultMessageSendingAction;
        }

        public SenderClass(Action<int> senderAction)
        {
            //Create a background worker
            _worker = new Thread(RunWorker) { IsBackground = true };
            _worker.Start();
            _senderAction = senderAction;
        }

        private void RunWorker() //This is the background worker's method
        {
            while (true) //Keep it running
            {
                lock (_myQueue) //No fiddling from other threads
                {
                    while (_myQueue.Count != 0) //Pop elements if found
                        SendMessage(_myQueue.Dequeue()); //Send the element
                }
                Thread.Sleep(50); //Allow new elements to be inserted
            }
        }

        private void SendMessage(int element)
        {
            _senderAction(element);
        }

        private void DefaultMessageSendingAction(int item)
        {
            /* whatever happens during sending */
        }

        public void AddToQueue(int element)
        {
            Task.Run(() => //Async method will return at ones, not slowing the caller
            {
                lock (_myQueue) //Lock queue to insert into it
                {
                    _myQueue.Enqueue(element);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
{
    private SenderClass _sender;
    private Queue<int> _messages;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _messages = new Queue<int>();
        _sender = new SenderClass(DummyMessageSendingAction);
    }

    private void DummyMessageSendingAction(int item)
    {
        _messages.Enqueue(item);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //This isn't a great test, but I think you get the idea
        int message = 42;
        _sender.AddToQueue(message);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(_messages, 42);            
    }
}
```

Comment: This way, the ``Queue<object> Messages`` will only be for test purpose, since it is for outgoing messages. I would rather Mock ``IMessageSender`` and check if ``SendMessage(...)`` have been called, and then test it separately afterwards.

But the SRP is nicely displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `SenderClass` should not perform any sending at all. It should simply maintain the queue. Inject an `Action<int>` through the constructor that does the sending. That way you can move `SendMessage` somewhere else and call it however you like.

As an added benefit your test of `SendMessage` is not cluttered with queue management.

Seeing your edit you don't seem to like this approach and you don't seem to like the `InternalsVisibleTo` approach either. You could expose `SendMessage` through a separate interface and implement that interface explicitly. That way `SendMessage` is still callable through that interface but by default it is not accessible without some casting contortions. It also does not show up in the intellisense autocomplete list.

Comment: I modified my answer before I saw this - you are referring to the Single Responsibility Principle, correct?

Comment: Let me look into ``Action<int>`` since I'm not familier with it.

Comment: You can also use an interface, does not matter. Same architecture, different call style.

Comment: Let me get this straight - I can forward a method to be executed, but does that need to be specified within the same class, or can it be from another?

Comment: Sure, it an be from another class. That's what delegates are for. Putting a method into a variable.